# missing argument label 'combine:' in call

Tags: arrays, swift

Getting the error shown below:

```
var products = [
    ("Kayak", "A boat for one person", "Watersports", 275.0, 10),
    ("Lifejacket", "Protective and fashionable", "Watersports", 48.95, 14)]

let stockTotal = products.reduce(0,{(total, product) -> Int in return total + product.4}); //missing argument label 'combine:' in call
```

In all examples I've seen of reduce, the combine label is not used:

```
let numbers = Array(1...10)
.reduce("numbers: ") {(total, number) in total + "\(number) "}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess I have seen this example some where else also ;)  :http://it-ebooks.org/book/apress/pro_design_patterns_in_swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the label if you use a trailing closure:

```
var products = [
    ("Kayak", "A boat for one person", "Watersports", 275.0, 10),
    ("Lifejacket", "Protective and fashionable", "Watersports", 48.95, 14)
]

let stockTotal = products.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.4 }
```

With a trailing closure the closure is supplied to the function after the final `)`.  If you don't want to use a trailing closure you need to add the argument label:

```
let stockTotal2 = products.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + $1.4 })
```

Comment: Dude! You are a pro. <http://it-ebooks.org/book/apress/pro_design_patterns_in_swift>

Answer (score 0):

Use the trailing closure syntax:

```
let stockTotal = products.reduce(0) {(total, product) -> Int in return total + product.4}
```